# Angular Project- Replace properties from External File in app.config.json

Tags: json, angular, tomcat, devops

I have Angular 7 application. I'm building it and generating Dist package. I would like to deploy this package on Tomcat or Apache web-server.

Now, I do not want to hard-code any values in app.config.json file. I would like to externalize these properties. Let's say, i have server.xml file or any other file in tomcat and values should be there and app.config.json should read property values from there.

How can I achieve this? Is there any other way, I can externalize my properties?

Comment: Maybe this article helps you https://pumpingco.de/blog/environment-variables-angular-docker/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you https://itnext.io/how-does-app-initializer-work-so-what-do-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-configuration-in-angular-718e7c345971.
Using this approach you can provide your configuration file directly to container (Tomcat or Apache Server) independently on environment.
If you use k8s, you can provide this config file through ConfigMap.